# "gtk_label_set_text: assertion 'GTK_IS_LABEL (label)' failed" when attempting to change label text in GTK+3 C

Tags: c, gtk3

So I have a label that is set when my program first launches, and is inside of a struct. Later in the program, if a button is pressed, I need that label change. When attempting to change the label, instead the following messages are printed to the terminal:

```
(NCX-Core-Lite:280991): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 10:10:06.868: invalid uninstantiatable type '(null)' in cast to 'GtkLabel'

(NCX-Core-Lite:280991): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 10:10:06.868: gtk_label_set_text: assertion 'GTK_IS_LABEL (label)' failed
```

The code I'm using to create/set/change the label is: (only including the parts relevant to the label)

```
gchar dwnldStr[32]="Ready.";

typedef struct{
    // Labels
    GtkWidget *w_lbl_status;
} app_widgets;

// PROBLEM AREA
void button1_download(GtkButton *button,app_widgets *wdgts){
  app_widgets *widgets = g_slice_new(app_widgets);
  gchar dwnldStr2[15]="Downloading...";
  gtk_label_set_text(GTK_LABEL(widgets->w_lbl_status),dwnldStr2);
  g_slice_free(app_widgets,widgets);
}

static void activate(GtkApplication *app,app_widgets *wdgts){
  ...
  app_widgets *widgets=g_slice_new(app_widgets);
  ...
  widgets->w_lbl_status=gtk_label_new(dwnldStr);
  gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(box),GTK_WIDGET(widgets->w_lbl_status),false,false,0);
  ...
  g_slice_free(app_widgets,widgets);
}
```

I've tried everything I've been able to find about using pointers and labels in GTK, but they either produce the same results or cause more errors. A few of those things are:

```
// Not creating a slice
void button1_download(GtkButton *button,app_widgets *wdgts){
  gchar dwnldStr2[15]="Downloading...";
  gtk_label_set_text(GTK_LABEL(wdgts->w_lbl_status),dwnldStr2);
}
```

```
// Declaring the label as a GtkLabel instead of a GtkWidget
typedef struct{
    // Labels
    GtkLabel *w_lbl_status;
} app_widgets;
void button1_download(GtkButton *button,app_widgets *wdgts){
  app_widgets *widgets = g_slice_new(app_widgets);
  gchar dwnldStr2[15]="Downloading...";
  gtk_label_set_text(widgets->w_lbl_status,dwnldStr2);
  g_slice_free(app_widgets,widgets);
}
static void activate(GtkApplication *app,app_widgets *wdgts){
  ...
  app_widgets *widgets=g_slice_new(app_widgets);
  ...
  gtk_label_set_text(widgets->w_lbl_status,dwnldStr);
  gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(box),GTK_WIDGET(widgets->w_lbl_status),false,false,0);
  ...
  g_slice_free(app_widgets,widgets);
}
```

Comment: It looks like `activate` creates an `app_widgets` object, sets its label, then frees it. And `button1_download` creates a new, unrelated `app_widgets` object and tries to do something with its (null) label. How are the `app_widgets` structs in these 2 functions related?

Comment: @Kevin I was not aware that creating the `app_widgets` object again in `button1_download` would create a new version of it. What you're saying is that there should only be one (I'm assuming it should be the one in `activate`), right?

Comment: Yes. You need to get the existing label from somewhere. I'm not familiar with the gtk API but I imagine you can set some custom user data when you set up `button1_download` to be called when the button is clicked? That custom data should include the label so you can grab it from inside `button1_download`. Or maybe you're supposed to get/set the label from the `app_widgets *wdgts` parameter in both functions instead of creating a new one yourself?

Comment: If I had to take a guess from what I've seen so far, I'm thinking it might be the latter? Unfortunately there are very few guides for GTK that use structs (and a lot of them also use UI files which I'm trying to avoid) so I don't have too much to go off of.

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid UI files? I've used gtkmm (gtk C++ wrapper library) and life was much easier using things like Glade to create the UI.

Comment: My biggest problem with them is that I haven't been able to figure out where to put them or how to bake them into the program. When I've used them in the past I've always had to use a relative path.